# Replace accented characters in string

Tags: php

I have a database which contains over 100,000 rows of user search queries, some of these strings contains accented characters such as

```
blodprøver
diarè
dårlig
```

What i am trying to do is after looping through the database replace the accented characters with normal characters such as ø with o, è with e.

When i run the below code, this works fine

```
$string = "blodprøver";

function removeAccents($str) {
$a = array('À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì',        'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'ÿ', 'Ā', 'ā', 'Ă', 'ă', 'Ą', 'ą', 'Ć', 'ć', 'Ĉ', 'ĉ', 'Ċ', 'ċ', 'Č', 'č', 'Ď', 'ď', 'Đ', 'đ', 'Ē', 'ē', 'Ĕ', 'ĕ', 'Ė', 'ė', 'Ę', 'ę', 'Ě', 'ě', 'Ĝ', 'ĝ', 'Ğ', 'ğ', 'Ġ', 'ġ', 'Ģ', 'ģ', 'Ĥ', 'ĥ', 'Ħ', 'ħ', 'Ĩ', 'ĩ', 'Ī', 'ī', 'Ĭ', 'ĭ', 'Į', 'į', 'İ', 'ı', 'Ĳ', 'ĳ', 'Ĵ', 'ĵ', 'Ķ', 'ķ', 'Ĺ', 'ĺ', 'Ļ', 'ļ', 'Ľ', 'ľ', 'Ŀ', 'ŀ', 'Ł', 'ł', 'Ń', 'ń', 'Ņ', 'ņ', 'Ň', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'Ō', 'ō', 'Ŏ', 'ŏ', 'Ő', 'ő', 'Œ', 'œ', 'Ŕ', 'ŕ', 'Ŗ', 'ŗ', 'Ř', 'ř', 'Ś', 'ś', 'Ŝ', 'ŝ', 'Ş', 'ş', 'Š', 'š', 'Ţ', 'ţ', 'Ť', 'ť', 'Ŧ', 'ŧ', 'Ũ', 'ũ', 'Ū', 'ū', 'Ŭ', 'ŭ', 'Ů', 'ů', 'Ű', 'ű', 'Ų', 'ų', 'Ŵ', 'ŵ', 'Ŷ', 'ŷ', 'Ÿ', 'Ź', 'ź', 'Ż', 'ż', 'Ž', 'ž', 'ſ', 'ƒ', 'Ơ', 'ơ', 'Ư', 'ư', 'Ǎ', 'ǎ', 'Ǐ', 'ǐ', 'Ǒ', 'ǒ', 'Ǔ', 'ǔ', 'Ǖ', 'ǖ', 'Ǘ', 'ǘ', 'Ǚ', 'ǚ', 'Ǜ', 'ǜ', 'Ǻ', 'ǻ', 'Ǽ', 'ǽ', 'Ǿ', 'ǿ', 'Ά', 'ά', 'Έ', 'έ', 'Ό', 'ό', 'Ώ', 'ώ', 'Ί', 'ί', 'ϊ', 'ΐ', 'Ύ', 'ύ', 'ϋ', 'ΰ', 'Ή', 'ή');
$b = array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 's', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'IJ', 'ij', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'OE', 'oe', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 's', 'f', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'A', 'a', 'AE', 'ae', 'O', 'o', 'Α', 'α', 'Ε', 'ε', 'Ο', 'ο', 'Ω', 'ω', 'Ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'ι', 'Υ', 'υ', 'υ', 'υ', 'Η', 'η');
return str_replace($a, $b, $str);
}

echo removeAccents($string);
```

However for some reason that is beyond me, this code does not change the characters

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
removeAccents($row['query']);
}
```

Why would the first one work but the second doesn't? they are both strings.

```
$string = "blodprøver";
echo removeAccents($string); //outputs blodprover YAYY!!

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$string = $row['SearchQuery']; // in this case $row['SearchQuery'] = blodprøver
echo removeAccents($string); //outputs blodprøver ERR?!!
}
```

Comment: 1. missing `]` 2. Maybe use `echo` to print it?! 3. What is the output of `var_dump($row["query"]):` ? 4. What does "doesn't work" mean? Any errors?

Comment: Strings are still immutable, you have to store that string somewhere or echo it ?

Comment: That was a mistake in pasting it here, i have used echo it prints it with the accented characters still in there.

Comment: @user3439600 Then still point 3 and 4 of my first comment ^ ? What's in the `$row["query"]` ?

Comment: And `$row['query']` is a string

Comment: $row['query'] is the strings from the database, blodprøver is one of them, however it doesn't replace the characters from a dynamic string such as $row, only if i declare a string such as $string = "blodprøver";

Comment: Sounds strange. It should be noted that [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#94946) could probably make this easier ?

Comment: Tried it, same issue

Comment: Well right now you just don't tell use the **full** and **real** story. Because with this shown code there is no way it can fail!

Comment: View edited code plz

Comment: Try `mb_detect_encoding` for both of your examples. `echo mb_detect_encoding($string)` and `echo mb_detect_encoding($row['SearchQuery'])` and see if they differ.

Comment: The normal strings from the database seem to be "ASCII" while the strings that contain the accented characters are "UTF-8"

Comment: @user3439600 and what about the string you're not extracting from database but assigning yourself?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by encoding the string first to UTF-8 then using the iconv

```
$string = utf8_encode($row['query']);
$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
```

Comment: utf8_encode deprecated

Answer (score -1):

Change the while loop with the following.

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
        echo removeAccents($row['query']);
        echo"<br>";
        }
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the OP's problem.